# Why does $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ closed, proper, convex imply that $f(x)+\|Ax-b\|^2$ attains a minimum?

Tags: convergence-divergence, convex-optimization, proximal-operators

I'm currently reading the paper ["Distributed Optimization and Statistical Learning via the Alternating Direction Method of Multipliers"](https://stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/papers/pdf/admm_distr_stats.pdf) by Boyd et al. about the alternating direction method of multipliers (ADMM). There, optimization problems of the form
$$
\min_x f(x)+\frac{\rho}{2}\|Ax+Bz-c+u\|^2
$$
are considered, where $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ is closed, proper, and convex, $\rho>0$, $A,B\neq0$ are fixed matrices, and $z,c,u$ are fixed vectors. These optimization problems arise as part of the ADMM. On page 16 of the manuscript the claim is made that, without further assumptions on $A$ and $B$, the above problem is solvable, i.e., a minimum exists/is attained. Unfortunately, no proof or reference is given. I've been trying to understand why that claim holds. In the hopes of being able to adapt an existing proof I've searched for results showing that the proximal operator
$$
\mathrm{prox}_f(y)=\arg\min_x f(x)+\|x-y\|^2
$$
(note that this is a set) is nonempty under the given conditions. However, adapting any of the proofs that I could find would require that:

- $f(x)+\frac{\rho}{2}\|Ax+Bz-c+u\|^2$ is strictly or strongly convex, which as far as I understand, can only be achieved by either requiring A to have full-column rank or by requiring $f$ to be strictly/strongly convex. References: *„First Order Methods in Optimization“, 2017, A. Beck,  Thm. 6.3, Thm. 5.25(a)* and *„Parallel and Distributed Computation: Numerical Methods“, 1989, D. Bertsekas, Prop. 4.1*
- $f(x)+\frac{\rho}{2}\|Ax+Bz-c+u\|^2$ is coercive, i.e., $\lim_{\|x\|\rightarrow\infty}f(x)+\frac{\rho}{2}\|Ax+Bz-c+u\|^2=\infty$, which as far as I can tell, is only possible if $A$ has full column rank or if $f$ is coercive. References: *„First Order Methods in Optimization“, 2017, A. Beck,  Thm. 6.4, Thm. 2.14*

Am I missing something? Can anyone provide an insight on how the claim may be proved using only the assumptions ($f$ closed, proper, convex) made in the paper?

Comment: If $A$ is $0$ and $f$ is unbounded below then a minimum value is not attained. So we must need some extra assumption on $A$ or on $f$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You're obviously correct. In the paper it is never explicitly mentioned that $A,B\neq0$ but it is implied. I changed the question accordingly.

Comment: Because $f$ is proper, it has to be unbounded below. If $f > M$ everywhere, then $f^{-1}([M, \infty]) = \Bbb R^n$, which is not compact.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I'm not sure I can follow. Why does a proper convex function have to be unbounded below? Could you please elaborate on your comment? In the proofs mentioned above, a level set is constructed and shown to be compact in order to show the existence of a minimizer. The problem in adapting the proofs is that here, using the same construction, such a level set may be closed but unbounded. Is that what you were thinking of?

Comment: Also some not so obvious assumptions must've been left out in the paper as what @littleO said still holds true, even when assuming that $A,B\neq0$. Think of $f(x)=x_1+e^{x_2}$ and $A=[0\quad 1]$ as an example (still unbounded below).

Comment: $f$ is proper means that for any compact set  $C$ in $\Bbb R \cup \{\infty\}, f^{-1}(C)$ is also compact. I am interpreting $\Bbb R \cup \{\infty\}$ as $(-\infty, \infty]$. So $[M, \infty]$ is a compact subset. But if $f > M$ everywhere, then $f^{-1}([M, \infty]) = \Bbb R^n$ is not compact, a contradiction. The other common topology on $\Bbb R \cup \{\infty\}$ is homeomorphic to a circle, with $\infty$ acting as both $+\infty$ and $-\infty$. But that is compact so there are no proper maps from $\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R \cup \{\infty\}$ in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't. In this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.02051 they construct a very easy counter example, and deduce sufficient conditions.

Answer (score 1):

A simple counter-example is the choice $n=1$, $A=0$, and $f(x)=e^x$. The example can be modified  to allow  $n>1$ and $A\ne0$.

You are right, some assumption is missing: the resulting functional needs to be coercive to guarantee existence of solutions.